# Why does sort take an Object array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, comparator, comparable

I just stumbled upon the following overloads of `sort` in `java.util.Arrays`:

```
public static void sort(Object[] a)

public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Why is the first overload not generic, but the second one is? Why does the first overload take an `Object[]` instead of a `Comparable[]`? The documentation even states:

> All elements in the array must implement the `Comparable` interface.

So what's the point of not verifying that constraint with Java's static type system?

Comment: Maybe the first one existed before generics were introduced?

Comment: @Oli It could still have taken a `Comparable[]` before generics, right?

Comment: Note that `TreeSet` has the same "bizzareness": you can actually created a `TreeSet` with a class not implementing `Comparable`, but then at runtime you'll get `ClassCastException`. Arrays are another problem though, since `A[]` is not the same as `B[]` at runtime, unlike genericized collections.

Comment: @fge: i think it is for compatibility reasons that `TreeSet` takes elements that do not implement `Comparable` if you provide a `Comparator`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method could be better if it were generic, but it would break compatibility with pre 1.5 code:

```
static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort(T[] a) {
    ...
}

static void main(String[] args) {
   Object[] a = {"1", "2"};
   sort(a); <- compile time error, need explicit cast sort((Comparable[])a);
}
```

While the second one compiles with 1.4 code with warning only

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c) {
    ...
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object[] a = { "1", "2" };
    sort(a, new Comparator() {   <-- warning 
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            return 0;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The first one method (`void sort(Object[] a)`) is not generic because:

1. it was introduced before generics appear in `Java`
2. it actually doesn't need generics

The second one requires generics, I think, only due to this construction `Comparator<? super T>`, because there isn't another convenient way to declare restrictions under second parameter with `Comparator` class.